# How do I change the highlighted background color inside the parenthesis?

Tags: faces, colors

I am using pretty much the default theme color however, I do want to change the highlighted background color inside the parenthesis.

Is there any specific Face Attributes setting for this specific case?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```lisp
(set-face-attribute 'show-paren-match-expression nil :background "yellow")
```

See [Faces](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Faces.html) in the Elisp manual, in particular [Face Attribute Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html), and [Matching Parentheses](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Matching.html).

If you want to tweak a face, positioning the cursor on a character and hitting `C-u` `C-x` `=` (`what-cursor-position`) will open a buffer with information about the faces used to display that character (that's how I found out about `show-paren-match-expression`). If you click on a face that interests you Emacs will open its documentation, saying in which library it's defined, with a link to the library. Click it. Most definitions have a `:group` keyword, for example `:group 'paren-showing-faces`. You can invoke `customize-group` and give it that keyword as argument, i.e. you can type `M-x customize-group RET paren-showing-faces RET` and you'll be brought to a buffer with a list of options for that topic.

Comment: Thank you. It solved! My face used to display was `sp-pair-overlay-face` so I've added `(custom-set-faces
 '(sp-pair-overlay-face ((t nil))))` and there is no highlighted background which what I wanted.

Comment: @kphex Wait [if you just want to disable it](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) ;-) you are better off using just `(setq show-paren-style 'parenthesis)`, provided you use `show-paren-mode` for highlighting matching pairs. See the manual at the Matching Parentheses node.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I wanted to do something with the highlighted color (light green color from my question).  `(setq show-paren-style 'parenthesis)` brought back the highlight for some reason... Thank you for your alternative suggestion though ;)

Comment: @kphex No need to apologize, I told you about that setting in case you could be better served by it :-)